# PHP: Atributo do tipo interface

Tags: php, interface, atributos, classes-abstratas, strategy-pattern

Estou fazendo um estudo de Padrões de Projetos. Meu primeiro padrão é o Strategy, onde eu tenho uma classe abstrata que tem dois atributos que devem receber instâncias de uma classe que implemente uma determinada interface.

As interfaces:

```
interface FlyBehavior
{
    public function fly();
}

interface QuackBehavior
{
    public function quack();
}
```

A classe abstrata:

```
abstract class Duck
{
    protected $flyBehavior;
    protected $quackBehavior;

    abstract function display();

    protected function performFly()
    {
        return $this->flyBehavior->fly();
    }

    protected function performQuack()
    {
        return $this->quackBehavior->quack();
    }
}
```

O ponto é o seguinte: tenho algumas classes que implementam FlyBehavior e QuackBehavior, e são essas classes desse tipo que devem ser atribuídas aos atributos $flyBehavior e $quackBehavior e eu gostaria de declarar da seguinte forma:

```
abstract class Duck
{
    protected FlyBehavior $flyBehavior;
    protected QuackBehavior $quackBehavior;
}
```

Porém se eu faço isso o editor acusa erro. Como posso fazer? Isso está errado? Pois eu sei que dá pra especificar o tipo de variável em parâmetros de funções, imagino que também seja possível em atributos, assim como em linguagens como Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, isto está errado. Não faz sentido você definir o tipo de um atributo em uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica. Isso só é possível em linguagens de tipagem estática, como o Java, que foi citado.

O que acontece é que você possui uma regra de negócio que deve ser aplicada sempre que houver uma atribuição ao atributo (*redundância?*), então você deve implementar esta regra de negócio em um método *setter*. Dado que o atributo pertence à classe `Duck`, basta implementar o método nesta classe:

```
abstract class Duck
{
    protected $flyBehavior;
    protected $quackBehavior;

    public function setFlyBehavior(FlyBehavior $behavior) {
        $this->flyBehavior = $behavior;
    }

    public function setQuackBehavior(QuackBehavior $behavior) {
        $this->quackBehavior = $behavior;
    }
}
```

Assim, como está definido o tipo do parâmetro no método, sempre que houver uma atribuição ao atributo será validado seu tipo. Como tais tipos são interfaces, até faz sentido fazer isso e é a única forma - exceto verificar o tipo no corpo do método *setter* utilizando `instaceof`.